# Django 1.10 query a table using username from logged in user

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django, creating a site where I want logged in users to see there own data provided in a table. This table has a field username.

I want the users to see there own data in a listview. I can't figure out how I can query, using the username from User. To give you an idea of what I am doing, this is what I have as code: (I tried multiple other ways, but I can't get a string with the User login Name.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User        
from django.views.generic import ListView      

username = User.username

class RoosterListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    queryset = Roosters.objects.filter(startvc__range=(DatumStart, DatumEind),username=CurrentUser).order_by("startvc")[:35]
```

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Note that the usual approach would be to name your model `Rooster` instead of `Roosters`, and use a foreign key to the `User` model instead of a string with the username.

Comment: I understand. And I will change Roosters into Rooster. But the data from the table Roosters is coming from another application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the username of your logged in user by

```
username = request.user
```

you can simply pass your request parameter around to get all the information of the current session and do whatever query you wanna do.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `username = User.username` line - `User` is the model class, not the current user instance.

You can access the current user if you set `queryset`, as this is loaded when the module is imported, not when the request is made. If you override the `get_queryset` method, you can access the user with `self.request.user`.

```
class RoosterListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Roosters.objects.filter(startvc__range=(DatumStart, DatumEind), username=self.request.user.username).order_by("startvc")[:35]
```